# API Gateway for playing media URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a media file linked to a URL (like https://songexample.mp3 (not the real url)). I want my app to play that audio, using something like

```
audio = new Audio('https://songexample.mp3')
audio.play()
```

But I would like to make it so that users cannot view the underlying URL itself, and also so that only logged in users can play the URL.

I am wondering if I can use API Gateway for this purpose. Through tutorials like [this one](https://dev.to/samueldaviddelacruz/protecting-your-resources-with-aws-cognito-and-api-gateway-1jk), it seems clear that you can link API Gateway to Cognito, so that only logged in Cognito users can access the API Gateway endpoint.

But, this example and the others I have seen assume you are using a REST endpoint, with a specific parameter (like id at the end), to get back information. In my case, the URL will not return text-based information, but will actually play media.

API Gateway seems to expect that the end of the URL will provide data for a {proxy} parameter--but my URL must end in mp3. Not surprisingly, when I've tried I've just gotten back 404 messages so far.

Is it possible to use API Gateway to limit access to this kind of URL?

Comment: Any ideas on how to protect media URLs?